# Use of article for each noun in a sentence

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

Can we use article with each noun separately in a sentence or one is enough as in the following sentence;

> Draw a car, a truck and a van.

Or

> Draw a car, truck and van

> Draw a car, truck and a van.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either with just the first, or with all of them. You can't scatter them non-uniformly outside of those two options.

Either the first distributes across the set through ellipsis, or there is no distribution, but you can't have mixed distribution.

Sometimes with long sentences and long noun phrases people get confused and repeat an article for the last one even though they omitted it for earlier ones. This is expected in casual conversation but frowned on in edited work.